# Why is Eclipse constantly searching for main types and how do I stop it?

Tags: eclipse

How do I stop Eclipse from searching for main types every time I run a Java application I have written?  Doesn't matter which file it is or how big it is, every time I run it I get the following (sorry I can't embed the image, you'll have to use the link):

[Searching for main types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aLUi.png)

It ALWAYS takes ages to do this, which means that I have a LONG delay before I can run programs.  It's frustrating as I teach Java and my students are always left wondering what's going on....

I've looked at other Stack Overflow questions in which people suggested setting up a run configuration, but when I do that I get the same problem.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with the current Eclipse with a fresh workspace and without additional plugins? If yes, please tell how. Please always show the whole window without cropping it. As a teacher, teach to focus on the problem (what information does knowing how frustrated you are provide and does it help to fix the issue you have?).

Comment: *How* are you telling Eclipse to run your application?

Comment: I am using a fresh workspace.  I run the application by clicking the green button on the taskbar.  That's how I always run files.  Strangely if I do this on one of the college computers I never have the problem, but I do have the problem on my work laptop.

Although interestingly, it's not doing it this morning....